# How to print required namespace?

Tags: clojure

I required namespace and I can use it:

```clj
(ns core
  (:require [hello :as h]))

(println h/x)
```

But why I can't print namespace only?

```clj
(println h) # Unable to resolve symbol: h in this context
```

I tried this with deps-tools and leiningen

Comment: Because `require` does not bind the symbol you indicate with `:as`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say `(println h)` you are asking to print the value bound to the symbol `h` in the current namespace. `h` is not interpreted as a namespace (or namespace alias) unless it is followed by a `/` character. So `(println h/x)` asks to print the value bound to the symbol `x` in the namespace referenced by the alias `h`, in other words, `hello.x`. You have not bound anything to the symbol `h` in your namespace, so `h` on its own is undefined.

If you want to look at the namespace itself, do something like `(println (the-ns 'hello))` (see https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/the-ns).